# Rasa slots not getting updated even after changing in Rasa interactive

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu

I  have given a query as ‘Top 5 brand groups’ and rasa correctly identifies the actions and entities.

[image]

The next query that I give is ‘Top 10’ . This should ideally fetch the same action. However rasa shows a wrong action but correct slots.  rectify the action and leave the slot entites as it is.

[image]

But when I correct the action and leave the slots unchanged it shows the right action but slots don’t get updated and it shows the last chat slots with number_to_drill as 5 instead of 10 which is the new. tried several times but always after correcting the action and confirming the slots it shows the current slots as the previous one and executes those.

[image]

Any suggestion on why the slot entities are not getting updated even after updating them in interactive tool will be really helpful.

Other details:

Rasa Version      :         3.6.4

Minimum Compatible Version: 3.5.0

Rasa SDK Version  :         3.6.1

Python Version    :         3.8.10

Comment: Please include your stories/rules and your custom action